# What does "in eius locum factus est" mean?

Tags: inscription

"in eius locum factus est" is an expression you see in the fasti consulares and I was wondering what it means.
Thank you.

Comment: "*In/at his/her/its place it is made.". It's hard to tell what's it supposed to mean without context.

Answer (score 3):

This phrase occurs when someone dies in office or abdicates office and another person replaces him.

```
[C. Servilius — f. — n. Stru]ctus Ahala [in mag. mortuus es]t

in eius loc. f[actus]. e[st]. [Opet. Verginius — f. — n. E]squilinus
```

Ahala died during his magistracy

in his place was appointed Esquilinus

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasti_Capitolini#Formulas_and_abbreviations) on the Fasti covers frequent abbreviations.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[fasti consulares capitolini](https://ia801607.us.archive.org/19/items/fasticonsulares00laurgoog/fasticonsulares00laurgoog.pdf)

[image: ag . mort.]

probably means: died in his place (in his function)

Occurs with abd. , removed, too.

Comment: Thank you very much!